# Possible to use django authentication for standalone YouTrack

Tags: django, youtrack

I love PyCharm, so I thought I'd give YouTrack a try.

I used [run-docker-container-as-service](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/run-docker-container-as-service.html) instruction, and I was able to create a service. I can start and stop the service with no issues.

Using a browser, I was able to do configuration, I can create users, issues, etc.

On the same system (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) I'm also running a django application. I would like for my django application users to submit issues, check status on issues, and possibly update issues they have submitted.

I want to make it as simple for my users as possible, so I would like to use django authentication for my YouTrack. That way, once a user is logged into my application, they don't need to go through a separate authentication process to use YouTrack.

It seems YouTrack offers multiple different authentication methods, but I don't see a django option. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no option to use Django authentication for YouTrack. The only option that came to my mind is a vice versa scenario with configuring YouTrack as a [SSO provider](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/SAML-2.0.html) and use the [django plugin](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth) for your application for authentication purposes.